# select 3 items with higher sales

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to select the 3 biggest selling records with this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_service` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;
```

the 'id_service' is the main column, the more sales, more records are added with the same 'id_service'.

so how do I do this without using PHP and select in descending order?

I tried this

```
select id_service, count(*) as id_service
from vendas WHERE id_service is not null
group by id_service order by id_service desc LIMIT 3
```

Comment: you have same name for two different things in your sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have aliased both columns to the same name.  No wonder the query is confused.  Try this:

```
select id_service, count(*) as cnt
from vendas WHERE id_service is not null
group by id_service
order by cnt desc
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: I almost did myself hehe